# Getting Monthly Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamics-ax-2012, ssis-2012

I want to extract all budget entries charged to the current year and cumulated over each month after .In January, taking the total over January, February take accumulated of January plus accumulated  February...
I started with this query :

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#BudgetTransTmp') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #BudgetTransTmp
Select  
        Row_number() over(ORDER BY YEAR(BTLine.DATE),MONTH(BTLine.DATE)) as RowNumber,
        COMBINATION.DISPLAYVALUE,
        BTLine.LedgerDimension                                      AS LedgerDimension,
        MIN(BTLine.TransactionCurrencyAmount)                       AS Amount,
        SUM(BTLine.TransactionCurrencyAmount)       
            OVER (ORDER BY YEAR(BTLine.DATE),MONTH(BTLine.DATE),BTLine.LedgerDimension,COMBINATION.DISPLAYVALUE )   AS SUM,
        YEAR(BTLine.DATE)                                           AS Year ,
        MONTH(BTLine.DATE)                                          AS MONTH 

INTO   #BudgetTransTmp 
FROM   MicrosoftDynamicsAX.dbo.BudgetTransactionLine                    AS BTLine


    --Get Display value
    INNER JOIN MicrosoftDynamicsAX.dbo.DIMENSIONATTRIBUTEVALUECOMBINATION AS COMBINATION
    ON  COMBINATION.RECID                                           = BTLine.LEDGERDIMENSION
GROUP BY   
            BTLine.LedgerDimension,
            YEAR(BTLine.DATE),
            MONTH(BTLine.DATE)
ORDER BY RowNumber
```

The result is :

```
    LedgerDimension Amount  SUM     Year    Month Display
1   22565448266     850.00  850.00  2012    8     601200-001-027--
2   22565448265     1700.00 2550.0  2012    12    601200-002-027--
3   22565448266     2700.00 5250.00 2012    12    601200-001-027--
4   22565448267     650.00  5900.00 2012    12    601400-002-027--
5   22565448268     1100.00 7000.00 2012    12    601400-001-027--
```

But i want to get

```
    LedgerDimension Amount  SUM     Year    Month Display
1   22565448266     850.00  850.00  2012    8     601200-001-027--
2   22565448265     1700.00 1700.0  2012    12    601200-002-027--
3   22565448266     2700.00 3350.00 2012    12    601200-001-027--
4   22565448267     650.00  650.00  2012    12    601400-002-027--
5   22565448268     1100.00 1100.00 2012    12    601400-001-027--
```

I think my COMBINATION of ORDER by (primary key) must be betwwen LedgerDimension ,Year ,  Month , Display

Any help in this regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to do is:

```
SUM(BTLine.TransactionCurrencyAmount)       
            OVER (PARTITION BY BTLine.LedgerDimension ORDER BY YEAR(BTLine.DATE),MONTH(BTLine.DATE),BTLine.LedgerDimension,COMBINATION.DISPLAYVALUE )   AS SUM
```

let me know if this works.